# Routing not working in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular

I'm trying to setup routing inside my application, but am getting following error in the console:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:138 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/angular2/router.js(…)
```

here is my **boot.ts**

```
// -- Typescript typings -------------------------------------------------------
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/jqueryui.d.ts" />



//Imports ----------------------------------------------------------------------
import {Component, enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  Router,
  RouteConfig,
} from 'angular2/router';



// -- Application Imports ------------------------------------------------------
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar.component';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home.page';



// -- Enable production module -------------------------------------------------
enableProdMode();



// -- Component ----------------------------------------------------------------
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent ],
    template: `
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})



// -- Routing ------------------------------------------------------------------
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', name: 'root', redirectTo: ['/Home'] },
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomePage }
])



// -- Class --------------------------------------------------------------------
export class MainApp {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}



// -- Bootstrap for application ------------------------------------------------
bootstrap(MainApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

and **index.html -----**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular2 starter</title>

    <!-- Application css -->
    <link href="dist/libraries/bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="dist/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>

<body>
    <main-app>Loading...</main-app>

    <!-- Application js -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/libraries/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

<!-- ES6-related imports -->
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    //configure system loader
    System.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});
</script>
<script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //bootstrap the Angular2 application
    System.import('dist/app/boot').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a script `router.dev.js` which is not shown very clearly in a lot of places and examples.

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Solved the issue, there is also router.min.js available for slightly lower file size.